# Google geolocation Json weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, geolocation

Hi I am using auto complete search location search box of google. It works fine. But i have a weird problem regarding what i get as a JSON format

```
//geolocation   
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {     
};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
//autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map); 

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
     $("#results").html('');
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    $("#results").append('<p> Latitude and Longtidute : '+place.geometry.location +'</p>');
    $("#results").append('<p> Address : '+place.formatted_address +'</p>');


    //extracting useful part    

    $.each(place.address_components, function() {
      if(this.types[0]=="route"){
           $("#results").append('<p> route : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
      } 

      if(this.types[0]=="locality"){
          $("#results").append('<p> locality : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
      } 


      if(this.types[0]=="administrative_area_level_2"){
          $("#results").append('<p> administrative area 2 : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
      } 

      if(this.types[0]=="administrative_area_level_1"){
          $("#results").append('<p> administrative area 1 : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
      } 


      if(this.types[0]=="country"){
          $("#results").append('<p> country : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
      } 
  });

    $("#results").append('<p> Places Name : '+place.name+'</p>');

    var searchAddressComponents = place.address_components;


    $.each(searchAddressComponents, function(){
      if(this.types[0]=="postal_code"){
          searchCountry=this.short_name;
      } 
  });
});
```

Now as you can see , i use long_name explicitly to catch long_name i.e. if i get canada, i want to get it as canada not as CA. but unfortunately, here it gives me out CA both in long_name and short_name. But very strange is that if i type the API request directly in web browser , it gives me full_name as canada only...may be i am missing some options in my code.

I am attaching some result for "The Toronto Condos, Capreol Court, Toronto, ON, Canada"
 code gives

Latitude and Longtidute : (43.640368, -79.39589699999999)

Address : 17 Capreol Court, Toronto, ON, Canada

route : Capreol Court

locality : Toronto

administrative area 1 : ON

country : CA

Places Name : The Toronto Condos

(mind ON & CA)

when i directly use browser http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=The+Toronto+Condos,+Capreol+Court,+Toronto,+ON,+Canada&sensor=false

it gives me

```
"results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Capreol Court",
               "short_name" : "Capreol Ct",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "CityPlace",
               "short_name" : "CityPlace",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Old Toronto",
               "short_name" : "Old Toronto",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Toronto",
               "short_name" : "Toronto",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Toronto Division",
               "short_name" : "Toronto Division",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Ontario",
               "short_name" : "ON",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Canada",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "M5V",
               "short_name" : "M5V",
               "types" : [ "postal_code_prefix", "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
```

Can you please check...

Comment: getting the correct data set is the trick usually, the correct administrative level, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get with the given link is a response of the geocoding-service.
But your code doesn't use geocoding, it's a implementation of places-autocomplete.

The response will be a [Place Details Response](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsResponses), what may differ from the results returned by the geocoding-service.